# Setting timeout in Stop-and-Wait protocol in UDP

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, udp

How should be the timeout of the socket be estimated in a `stop-and-wait` protocol over UDP? Can it be just any arbitrary integer multiple of the round-trip-time (RTT)?

Comment: The timer should be set to some value that is longer than the average round-trip time so that the timeout will indicate a likely loss. Setting the timer to a too-short value will result in excess duplicate packets. Although the protocol can deal with them, we’d like to avoid an excessive amount of unnecessary retransmissions. It will just increase the traffic and hence congestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you want the timeout to be equal to the exact time it takes from the moment you've sent a packet, until the moment you receive the acknowledgement from the other party - this pretty much the RTT.

But it's almost impossible to know the exact ideal timeout in advance, so we have to guess. Let's consider what happens if we guess wrong.

If we use a timeout which happens to be lower than the actual RTT, we'll timeout before the ack had time to arrive. This is known as a *premature timeout*, and it's bad - we're re-transmitting a packet even though the transmission was successful.

If we use a timeout which happens to be higher than the actual RTT, it'll take us longer to identify and re-transmit a lost packet. This is also bad - we could have identified the lost packet earlier and re-transmitted it.

Now, about your question:

> Can it be just any arbitrary integer multiple of the round-trip-time
>   (RTT)?

First of all, the answer is **yes**. You could use any positive integer, from 1 to basically infinity. Moreover, you don't even have to use an integer, what's wrong with a multiplier of x2.5?

But what's important is to understand is what would happen with different multipliers. If you pick a low multiplier such as 1, you'd run into quite a few *premature timeouts*. If you pick a large number, such as 100, you'd have many *late timeout*, which will cause your transmissions to halt for long periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course for setting a timeout nothing better than learning from how TCP does it. 
http://sgros.blogspot.com/2012/02/calculating-tcp-rto.html

At the beginning you have to begin with an arbitrary timeout and it must be sufficiently high. Say 3 seconds. This should be enough for most communications considering in most cases the other part is responding much faster. Then based on the measured Round Trip Time you change the retransmission timeout dynamically. For example, a simple algorithm, you could set your timeout at 2 * RTT, if you have a timeout you increase your retransmission timeout exponentially until you receive a response. When you receive a response you re-calculate your timeout again to the new 2 * RTT.

Calculating it dynamically, your protocol will be able to adapt to different types of networks and different geos and situations.

You could make it more complex and can do it in the same way TCP does it.